# block function run when it is passed as parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var event = function(id) {
    alert(id);
}

textProgressBar.generator('20', text1, event("test"));

this.generator = function (percentage, text, event, type) {
    ....
    $(this.id).children().last().on('click', event);
}
```

I want to run function when it is clicked.
But it's function run when page is loaded.

```
textProgressBar.generator('20', text1, event("test"));
```

If I pass the parameter to `event` function, it run when page is loaded.

How can I block this function when page is loaded?

Comment: you can't block things without `alert`, `confirm` or `prompt`.

Comment: this line `textProgressBar.generator('20', text1, event("test"));` executes the command ... don't do that and it wont run

Comment: don't use `event` for a var/function name - messy in at least internet explorer

Comment: ^^ What Jaromanda X said, at least at global scope. IE (and Chrome, which provides it as a sop to IE-specific code) has a global `event` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
textProgressBar.generator('20', text1, event("test"));
```

*calls* `event` and passes its return value into `textProgressBar.generator`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you want to pass the function into `generator`, you'll need to pass a function reference rather than calling the function.

Two ways to do that:

1. A wrapper function:

   ```
   textProgressBar.generator('20', text1, function() { event("test"); });
   ```

   There, we create a function (an anonymous one) that, when caled, will call `event` passing in `"test"` as an argument.
2. `Function#bind`:

   ```
   textProgressBar.generator('20', text1, event.bind(null, "test"));
   ```

   `Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original with a given `this` value (`null` in my example) and any arguments you give `bind` (`"test"` in my example).

Comment: 3. return a function from `event`: `var event = function(id){ return function(){ alert(id) } }` ;)

Comment: @pawel: That's really just #1, but putting it in a function. We start down that road, we'll recurse endlessly (e.g., we can also put *that* in a function, which we can *also* put in a function, which...). :-) But that said, factories like that were pretty common prior to `Function#bind`.